# Removing sections from CGMutablePath

Tags: ios, swift, macos, core-graphics, cgpath

For this project, I'm using the `addCurve` method of `CGMutablePath` to draw a curve-shape on a view.

What I'm not understanding at all, is how (or whether it's even possible) to remove that exact same curve from the mutable path? Judging by the API, it looks like there are lots of methods for adding various shapes at different points, but no methods on how to remove them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not possible, you may hold the elements of the original path so you can construct a new one just with the elements you want or, you can use [CGPath.applyWithBlock](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpath/2873218-applywithblock) to construct a new one selecting the wanted elements.

Comment: OK, that makes sense - but would it be possible to just "delete" a path and create a new one?

Comment: I assume what you mean is cleaning a path that’s already drawn, if that’s the case you can’t remove t directly, you have to invalidate the view and draw just what you need. You invalidate the view with setNeedsDisplay that cause drawRect to be called again